# Grails - Updating a table with data that already exists during an AJAX call

Tags: ajax, grails, html-table

I have a little dilemma and believe this could be a design issue. I have a list of contacts returned to my view (searchResults) based on some criteria (check boxes, etc). Essentially an advanced search.

Each contact has three links in a field set that either allows editing, showing details, or 'hitThis'. The hitThis method performs a series of tasks that will generate three new values for a contact - age, size, speed. When I click that link, I want to basically update that row only with the new values (columns already exist, just empty).

I have a div in my gsp that contains a table that displays the searchResults list. During my form submit for the search results, I return a list of contacts that updates my template where the div exists. This works fine.

In that div, I have a form as such:

```
<td>
  <g:form>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
      <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${contactInstance?.id}" />
      <g:set var="searchResults" value="${searchResults}" /><br/>
      <g:set var="cID" value="${contactInstance?.id}" /><br/>
      <g:actionSubmit class="edit" action="edit" value="${message(code: 'Edit')}"/>
      <g:actionSubmit class="show" action="show" value="${message(code: 'Show')}"/>
      <g:remoteLink action="hitThis" value="Click Me" update="searchResultsDiv" params="[searchResults:searchResults, cID:cID]"/>
    </fieldset>
  </g:form>
</td>
```

When I  select the remote link for hitThis, I want to perform an action that will update three columns that are attached to that contactInstance row in the searchResults template:

Before click:

```
myName  age  size  speed
Tom     empty empty empty
```

After click:

```
myName age size speed
Tom    20   6    4.9
```

I thought the rendering would handle it, but the call to hitThis won't return the searchResults list (which could be quite large) that was initially passed to update that table. I would prefer not passing BACK the list, since I feel this is excessive and performance crippling.

I could just redirect the user to that contact's information page (show), but I would rather update the table on the fly.

How can I simply update a div or even a table row, after my hitThis call and without having to pass everything back to the controller to only have to pass it back again?

---

Edit:

So my results now according to the example you gave me is similar to this (name is Ted, size is 5, speed is 4:

```
name     size    speed
Ted54   Ted54    Ted54
```

Here is part of my view:

```
<td id="name-${contactInstance.id}"><g:render template="name" model="['contactInstance':contactInstance]"/></td>
<td id="size-${contactInstance.id}"><g:render template="size" model="['contactInstance':contactInstance]"/></td>
<td id="speed-${contactInstance.id}"><g:render template="speed" model="['contactInstance':contactInstance]"/></td>

<fieldset class="buttons">

    <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${contactInstance?.id}" />
    <g:remoteLink action="moreInfo" params="['cid':contactInstance?.id]" onSuccess="updateData(data,'${contactInstance?.id}'), updateData2(data,'${contactInstance?.id}'), updateData3(data,'${contactInstance?.id}')" >TEST</g:remoteLink>
</fieldset>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
    <script>
        function updateData(data, id) {
            alert(data);
            $('#name-'+id).html(data);
        }

        function updateData2(data, id) {
            alert(data);
            $('#size-'+id).html(data);
        }

        function updateData3(data, id) {
            alert(data);
            $('#speed-'+id).html(data);
        }
    </script>
```

And my controller method:

```
def moreInfo() {
    def contactInstance = Contact.get(params.cid)

    contactInstance.name= "Ted"
    contactInstance.size= "5"
    contactInstance.speed= "4"

    if (contactInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        println(contactInstance)
    }

    render(template:'name', model:[contactInstance:contactInstance])
    render(template:'size', model:[contactInstance:contactInstance])
    render(template:'speed', model:[contactInstance:contactInstance])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate your DOM using javascript after the remote call returns.

(I'm not sure why you need to pass the entire searchResults with the remote call. It could be a rather large structure. You may consider storing it in the session instead and manipulate it over there. Of course, this is a design decision for you to take.)

Another way to think about this is to create a template for the form. Then render that template with the remote call (replacing the existing one within the td).

template: _myform.gsp

```
  <g:form>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
      <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${contactInstance?.id}" />
      <g:set var="searchResults" value="${searchResults}" /><br/>
      <g:set var="cID" value="${contactInstance?.id}" /><br/>
      <g:actionSubmit class="edit" action="edit" value="${message(code: 'Edit')}"/>
      <g:actionSubmit class="show" action="show" value="${message(code: 'Show')}"/>
      <g:remoteLink action="hitThis" value="Click Me" update="searchResultsDiv" params="[searchResults:searchResults, cID:cID]"/>
    </fieldset>
  </g:form>
```

then your normal page gsp can be:

```
...
<tr>
  <td>
    <g:render template="myform" />
  </td>

  <td>
    <g:render template="myform" />
  </td>
</tr>
...
```

and in the 'hitThis' action,

```
def hitThis() {
    ...
    render(view: "myform")
}
```

finally, use javascript to replace the form in the 'td' at the client end

Comment: I added some additional code from my example. Do I need to handle a render for each table column entry? Could I handle all 3 in one template?

Comment: you can use a single template and use a model to customize the response. see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html

Comment: OK excellent - I think I have got that going. I have a template for the contactRow and hitThis is attempting to render the new view. How do I use javascript to "refresh" the tds for the contact? I placed all contact details in the template and each of the properties for the contact are represented as a TD (I want to refresh just those 3).

Comment: simple hook into the <g:remoteLink onSuccess="updateContact(data)" /> and write a javascript function "updateContact(data)". Within it, use jquery to find the td and replace the contents with 'data'

Comment: So would I passed the model from the control to the javascript method updateContact? Such as updateContact(<model param name>, <model param age>, <model param speed>)?

Comment: not really, 'data' will contain the HTML return from hitThis, so you just need to replace it within the td

Comment: this is hard to describe here, so I wrote some sample code here https://github.com/aldrinm/grails-sample-code. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Is there a way to parse the data in the javascript? It passes all three of my columns at once, so when I update it updates my name column, but then adds two extra columns.

Comment: I figured I can update each of the columns using the innerHTML, which seems to be working.

Comment: I've updated according to my changes - I think I am just about there, it's handling the data correctly to separate according to the data I actually need.